# How to prevent from adding new topic to a record with the specific status?

Tags: trigger, topics

Topic is a useful feature to categroize record easily. However, it is too easy adding new topic to make a good management of data.

I design a status field to controll the behavior with trigger controll but it fails. It seems that adding a new topic to the record does not alter the update trigger.

In the case, what will the best practices to prevent from adding new topic to a specfic record?

For an example: I don't want user to add new topic if the record's status is 'New'.

[image]

I tried to create a trigger of this but it does not work for the purpose.

```
trigger cObj1_Trigger on cObj1__c (before update, after update) {
  if(Trigger.isBefore){
    for(cObj1__c c: Trigger.old){
      if(c.Status__c == 'Published'){
        c.addError('No update - before update - (Status: ' + c.Status__c + ')');
      }
    }}
  }else if(Trigger.isAfter){
    for(cObj1__c c: Trigger.old){
      if(c.Status__c == 'Published'){
        c.addError('No update - after update - (Status: ' + c.Status__c + ')');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The trigger does not fire upon a new topic is added to the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topic's association to an SObject is via `TopicAssignment` object which you can write a trigger on

(untested)

```
trigger TopicAssignmentTrigger on TopicAssignment (before insert) {

  // Pass 1 - get relevant parent objects
  Set<Id> cObj1Ids = new Set<Id>();
  for (TopicAssignment ta: Trigger.new) {
       cObj1Ids.add(ta.EntityId); 
  }
  Map<Id,CObj1__c> excludedCObj1sById = new Map<Id,cObj1__c> (cObj1Ids.isEmpty()  
     ? new List<cObj1__c>()
     : [SELECT Id, Status__c FROM cObj1__c 
          WHERE Id IN :cObj1Ids]);
  
  // Pass 2 - disallow topic if Status = new
  for (TopicAssignment ta : Trigger.new) {
      if (excludedCObj1sById.containsKey(ta.EntityId) &&
          excludedCObj1Map.get(ta.EntityId).Status__c == 'New') {
         ta.addError('No topic allowed for status New cObj1s');
      }
   } 
}
```